# MySQLi: Can't Bind Results to Variables

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

The following script queries the database for customer by their unique token. It then queries the database once again to check if there's a row in the "account_modules" table. If not, a row is to be created and set the "aid" column to the customer's unique ID.

I am getting the "clientid" variable set to 0. Echoed values below code. Thanks for your help in advance!

```
<?php 

//Required file for database config
require_once('../includes/config.php');

//Set the GLOBAL GET to variable
$token = htmlspecialchars($_GET['token']);

//Set the search query with unbinded values
$search = $connection->prepare("SELECT id, client, email, plan, uniqueval FROM account WHERE uniqueval = ?");

//Bind variable to SELECT query
$search->bind_param("s", $token);

//Execute query through IF statement
if ($search->execute()) {

    //Bind the results to their variables through the if statement
    if ($search->bind_result($clientid, $business, $email, $plan, $newtoken)) {

        echo $token . "<br />" . $clientid . "<br />" . $business . "<br />" . $email . "<br />" . $plan . "<br />" . $newtoken;

        //Close this database query
        if ($search->close()) {

            //Set the query string to search unbinded perameter
            $valconfig = $connection->prepare("SELECT aid FROM account_modules WHERE aid = ?");

            //Set the perameter 'WHERE aid = ?' to the query
            $valconfig->bind_param("s", $clientid);

            //Execute the query through MySQLi
            $valconfig->execute();

            //Stores the number for counting
            $valconfig->store_result();

            //Count the number of bulletins today
            $unique_count = $valconfig->num_rows;

            //Close the session with the results to username check
            $valconfig->close();

            if ($unique_count == 0) {

                //Set the query string to search unbinded perameter
                $insert = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO account_modules (aid) VALUES (?)");

                //Set the perameter 'VALUES = (?)' to the query
                $insert->bind_param("s", $clientid);

                if ($insert->execute()) {

                    $created = "config";

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

?>
```

Echod Values

```
74b450bf7b42a3499dc4a8f9b5a69cca

0

[blank]

[blank]

[blank]

[blank]
```

Comment: Side comment: searching and then inserting can lead to a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). If `aid` is supposed to be unique mark it that way in the database. Then you just need to do an `INSERT IGNORE` and check [affected_rows](http://nz1.php.net/mysqli_affected_rows) to verify whether the record was inserted.

Comment: @MikeW - Unfortunately, I set 'aid' to unique and INSERT IGNORE in the insert query. I have the same results. Is there any other way I can write this code to give me similar results? Thanks!

Comment: As I said: this was a side note - just a comment on your overall approach. A closer look suggests that you have bound the result variables, but not called `$search->fetch()` to retrieve the data.

Comment: Thank you @MikeW, I was going crazy.